# Безопасно ли использование UUID в URL если под URL будут хранится конфиденциальные данные

Tags: django, uuid

Есть интернет-магазин, где есть каталог товаров, корзина, оформление заказа. У меня вопрос по поводу оформление заказа. есть `url` > `/order` под этим урлом идет оформление заказа, есть форма и пользователь вписывает в них свои данные, а это `ФИО`, `номер телефона` и `адрес`, сами понимаете что это конфиденциальные данные, которые никому кроме пользователя лучше не видеть. И после оформления заказа осуществляется переадресация на `url` > `/order/номер заказа` и там выдается идентификатор заказа (номер заказ) и перечисляются данные пользователя и тот товар, который заказал пользователь. Так вот под номером заказа используется `uuid` то есть выходит следующий `url` > `/order/c9aba690-2c0d-4e8f-876f-102fd60b4ddf` и я понял что введя тот идентификатор в `url` который знает пользователь он получит сущность заказа и приватные данные. Так вот вопрос может ли он узнать идентификаторы других пользователей? Сможет ли любой пользователь зайти на сайт и каким-нибудь перебором перебрать все возможные варианты и получить идентификатор какого-нибудь заказчика, затем ввести его в `url`и получить страницу с данными `/order/номер заказа`? Или с `uuid` это невозможно? Просто я беспокоюсь за безопасность данных заказчиков.

**views.py**
Данный метод отвечает за создание заказа, то есть возвращает форму для заполнения клиента и в случае успешных, валидных данных переадресует на урл `order_success` где и выводятся номер заказа пользователя и его данные

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        order = Order.objects.order_by('id').last()
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order, product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear_session()

        return redirect(reverse('order:order_success', kwargs={'pk':order.id}))
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'orders/order_create.html', {'cart':cart, 'form':form})
```

`Order` модель имеет поля заполнения данных информации о клиенте, номер, телефон и т.д, а `OrderItem` хранит данные заказа, цена, кол-во и т.д и все эти данные передаются в шаблон `order_succes.html`, которые выдается под урлом `/order/c9aba690-2c0d-4e8f-876f-102fd60b4ddf`

```
def order_success(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=pk)
    return render(request, 'orders/order_success.html', {'order':order, 'order_item':order_item})
```

Так вот сможет ли рандом пользователь зайти на сайт и узнать номер заказа другого пользователя каким-нибудь хакерским перебором, безопасен ли мой вариант? или лучше использовать что-то другое для более лучшей безопасности. Этот вопрос относится не только к `Django` пользователям, но и всем кто понимает что-то в безопасности. Помогите пожалуйста с решением данного вопроса.

Comment: Сможет конечно. Вопрос только в том, сколько времени займёт перебор — не исключено, что это время превышает время существования Вселенной

Comment: Естественно, UUID должен быть случайно сгенерированным (UUIDv4), иначе он будет просто предсказуемый и даже перебирать ничего не надо

Comment: Если вы уж даёте доступ просто по ссылке и не сделали никакую аутентификацию, то нужно позаботиться, чтобы [ссылка не оказалась в поисковиках](https://habr.com/ru/post/416219/) — добавить X-Robots-Tag хотя бы

Comment: Почему бы просто не выбрасывать 403-ю ошибку при попытке доступа не к своему заказу?

Comment: @andreymal Да, uuid сгенерированный) и да про robots.txt знаю, такие ссылки не будут попадать в поисковики, спасибо

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, К сожалению я не знаю как это сделать просто и без лишнего кода, скорее всего нужно прописывать логику аутентификация и регистрации и присваивать каждый заказ к определенному юзеру, но как по мне это лишние хлопоты и аутентификации в данном магазине не будет, ибо движок пишется с минимализмом и простотой)

Comment: В Django это делается буквально в пару-тройку строк.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev использование сессий? или как-то по другому?

Comment: Наверное имеется ввиду что объект Request содержит пользователя.

Comment: @avtomato без аутентификации request.user имеет значение AnonymousUser, возможно ли определенный заказ присвоить к AnonymousUser?